# How to set text color for all the elements from an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist, onclicklistener

I have created programmatically, 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. Every radio button represents an answer to a question. So i want to do this. When someone checks the correct answers from the radio groups, i want to add all of them in an `ArrayList` named `correctAnswerRadios`. Same with the wrong answers. I set also a `OnClickListener` on a button. I want also to make all the correct answers green and the wrong answers red, when someone presses the button. With this code, i get this error: 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array'.

Here is my code:

```
RadioGroup[] answerGroup;
RadioButton[] answer;
Button finishButton;
RadioButton[] checkedRadioButton;
ArrayList<RadioButton> correctAnswerRadios;
ArrayList<RadioButton> wrongAnswersRadios;

    correctAnswerRadios = new ArrayList<>();
    wrongAnswersRadios = new ArrayList<>();
    answerGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];

    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        answerGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answer[j].setId(j + 100);
                answer[j].setTag(String.valueOf(an.getCorrect_answer()));
                answerGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);

                answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    private boolean isChecked = true;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                            checkedRadioButton[j] = ((RadioButton) v);
                            int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton[j].getTag().toString());
                            if (checkedRadioButton[j].isChecked() & CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                                correctAnswerRadios.add(checkedRadioButton[j]);
                            } else {
                                wrongAnswersRadios.add(checkedRadioButton[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(answerGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < answerGroup.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                    RadioButton correctRadio = correctAnswerRadios.get(j);
                    correctRadio.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    RadioButton wrongRadio = wrongAnswersRadios.get(j);
                    wrongRadio.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    answerGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated .Thanks!

Comment: You want to if user click the correct answer this answer becames green color and the rest red, and if the user clicks the wrong answer it becames red and the rest 2 red 1 green?

Comment: No, all i want is that when some presses the button, the correct checked answers to became green and the wrong answers red. That's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init checkedRadioButton like

```
checkedRadioButton = new RadioButton[size];
```

and change your finishButton listener method to

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

//Disable buttons
 for (int i = 0; i < answerGroup.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {

         answerGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);

     }
 }
 //put button colors

 for(RadioButton correct: correctAnswerRadios){
  correct.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 }

 for(RadioButton wrong: wrongAnswersRadios){
  wrong.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array.  For instance:

```
checkedRadioButton = new RadioButton[size];
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just did. Now the emulator doesn't crush when it starts, it crushes when i try to check a radio button. This is the error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`. What can i do?

Comment: You need to initialize the checkRadioButton array - you have no members.  I don't see any code that goes someting like checkRadioButton[0] = x.

Comment: I don't think you need checkedRadioButton[j] at all - you can just use answer[j].

Comment: Please, can you be more specific? Maybe, can you help me writing some code? All i want is that when someone presses the button, the correct checked answers to became green and the wrong answers red. That's it!